# rename or move on close_write?

Tags: bash, rename, inotify

I've been driving myself crazy trying to figure this out.

```
inotifywait -m -r -e close_write --format '%?' folder
```

How can I take the specific file that triggers this event and rename and then move it, or move and rename it? By renaming I mean to replace the whitespaces with non-alphanumeric characters such as underscores, dashes, etc. Acceptable alternative would be to either prepend or append the filename with a unique-to-my-purpose identifier so that I can sort them into specific folders after processing. Specifically movies will end up in the movies folder, etc.

I have the whole processing aspect of it working, but don't possess the skills to achieve my goal.

It doesn't have to be `inotifywait`, I'm open to just about anything (except Windows) that I can achieve with some shell scripting.

Can it do a search for a file that was last modified n seconds ago? If so, check same file after a 30 second sleep to make sure it hasn't changed, then act upon it? I need a way to separate completed files from files that haven't finished downloading.

I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the time issue wasn't critical I set the whole thing up as a cron job looking for files that were modified MORE than one minute earlier `mmin +1`, on an hourly basis and when I checked back my files had not been moved and my terminal had a "no such file or directory" message on it. I guess `rename` doesn't recurse.

A couple of hours googling took me to this page: *[Find file then cd to that directory in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458461/find-file-then-cd-to-that-directory-in-linux)*.

Now starting in my new videos folder

```
cd -- "$(find ./ -name "*S0*" -type f -printf '%h' -quit)"
find ./ -type f -mmin +1 -exec rename 's/\ /\%/g' {} \;
mv -t /home/terry/Video_Processing/staging "*%*"
```

Set up in cron moves all completed files to the staging area leaving the one still downloading for the next pass.

Answer (score 0):

After a much needed break I decided to take another swing at my original plan of using `inotifywait` to trigger the rename/move/convert process. It was painfully obvious that file had to have been created MORE than 60 seconds previously for `mmin` to catch the file(s), so first the trigger, followed by a 61 second sleep before initiating the rename.

I'm using `iwatch` as it allows recursivity. As long as the files are named in the fashion `titleS0xExx.ext`, with the digits 0-9 replacing the x's, it seems to work fine. Here's the relevant portion of the only part where recursion is neccessary.

```
watch=/home/terry/New_Video/TV_Show
events=close_write,move_to
excluded=
recursive=false
autoadd=false
command=cd /home/terry/New_Video/TV_Shows
command=sleep 61
command=cd -- "$(find ./ -name "S0" -type f -printf '%h' -quit)"
command=find ./ -type f -mmin +1 -exec rename 's/\ /\%/g' {} \;
command=mv -t /home/terry/Video_Processing/staging *%*
command=find /home/terry/New_Video/TV_Shows -empty -type d -delete
```

The movies and other folders need the 61 second sleep as well.

The time delay is not an issue in this case. It isn't a perfect solution, but it is about as close as "damn" is to swearing.

For some reason it didn't remove the empty folder so some tweaking may be needed.

Comment: these commands are supposed to be one separate lines, guess I need to read up on quoting.